# calling exports node.js function from front-end js using firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send emails using js on firebase and am struggling to call back-end functions through firebase.

Here is the simple function I would like to call (inside index.js)

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   return 1;
 });
```

I would like to be able to call it through my script or external js like so:

```
  function sendEmail()
  {
    var testFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');
    alert(testFunction());
  }
```

^ This is inside the script tag of the index.html file

I've tried following https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable
but have trouble understanding it

I've also tried seeing how this example of an email sender works and work with that but all the functions are triggered by the event of a user logging in or deleting their account: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users#functions-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps given in the link: [Set up your local environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment). Then add the following function.

```
function sendEmail() {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test')().then(function(result) {
            // Handle result of your cloud function.
            resolve(data)
        }).catch(function(err){
            //Handle error
            reject(err)
        });
   })
}
```

Now you can call this function anywhere. Your mistake was that you were calling sendEmail() as a synchronous function but it is an asynchronous function.

Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I tried out your solution but im getting a firebase.functions is not a function error

its underlining: firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test').then(function(result) {
with that message when i try run your code

Comment: It seems that you haven't installed firebase in your local environment. First setup firebase and then implement my code.

Comment: the same script contains functions that do firebase authentication like logging in and deleting account, etc so wouldnt that mean firebase is there?

Comment: Can you check if you have included firebase-functions like : <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-functions.js"></script> or npm module of firebase-functions. You must have included dependency for auth and other things but not functions

Comment: there are scripts included for firebase-app, auth, database and init im pretty sure. Ill try add functions

Comment: i tried adding: <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase-functions.js"></script> but I dont think it worked

Comment: im pretty sure it's failing to file firebase-functions, it's saying failed to load resource in the browser console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176468/discussion-between-mark922-and-taka).

Comment: thanks for all the help, I managed to import the functions in the end and your solution in the discussion chat worked!, could you please fix the one in our solution here to match it and i'll mark it as the solution

Comment: sorry that I didn't notice, thanks for the help and tolerating my in-out activity

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.